# Redshift: How to Create a Function which Uses a Lookup Table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a Roster Table.

```
Id int primary key,
Name varchar(100)
```

And I want to create a function fnGetRoster(int) which will return the name by searching the Roster Table.

Like this:

```
create or replace function fnGetRoster(int)
returns varchar(100)
stable
as $$
    select name from Roster where Id = $1
$$ language sql
```

I find this so hard to do in RedShift, as I cannot use from, where, etc.

What could I do? Did I use function incorrectly?

================== Newly added information (After 1 answer) ====================

I see lots of people mentioned about stored procedure and join. Thanks but please forgive me that I didn't describe the whole problem very well, As the original problem is a little bit long, so I asked the simple version.
I am migrating an old table and creating new structure. One of the field contains something like this

```
Category
CatA : CatB : CatC : ..... : CatX
```

where the other table called Category

```
Id     ParentId      CategoryName 
-----+-------------+-----------------
1    |    NULL     | CatA
-----+-------------+-----------------
2    |    1        | CatB
-----+-------------+-----------------
3    |    2        | CatC
-----+-------------+-----------------
4    |    3        | CatD
-----+-------------+-----------------
```

Bad thing is, there is no categoryID kind of thing in this table, so I have to analyse the whole string in order to figure out the CategoryId. I cannot use the last part of the string directly as there is no guarantee the name is unique. (but there is guarantee that the full category name is unique). I am hoping to write a function that can do the analyse and then comes out with an Id, but I find that **functions seems to be designed for different purpose from RedShift**...
Now I am struggling with the procedures... And I am considering to move this data migration task out of Redshift (Only use it to store the result)

Comment: Redshift does not allow to use FROM, INTO, WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, LIMIT in the function. Please see
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-sql-udf.html

Comment: you should be considering using joins of course

Comment: Lot of times (Not for a query) this is being used and if there is a function that will be nice. Joins can do the work but make things a lot complicate.

Comment: Its SQL! joins are what you use.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a [Stored Procedure in Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html), rather than a Scalar User-Defined Function.

However, given your use-case, this is not advisable. It would be quite inefficient and would result in poor performance.

You should use a `JOIN` to obtain such data, for example:

```sql
SELECT
  something,
  roster.name
FROM other_table
JOIN roster ON (other_table.roster_id = roster.id)
```

This will be highly optimized for selection.